# Replacing getchar with fgetc or getc in while(getchar() != '\n');

Tags: c, getchar, fgetc, getc

People usually mention

```
while( getchar() != '\n' )
```

when it comes to clearing the input buffer or overflow.

`fgetc` or `getc` also work. For example:

```
while( fgetc(stdin) != '\n' )
```

and

```
while( getc(stdin) != '\n' )
```

Is there any particular reason why people always use `getchar`?

Is there any disadvantage to using `fgetc` or `getc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People prefer `getchar` only in situations when they read from standard input. There is no reason why one wouldn't replace it with `getc`/`fgetc` when reading from a file is needed.

With this said, the construct is dangerous, because it can lead to an infinite loop in situations when there is no `'\n'` in the input stream. For example, if end-user closes the stream with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, a program with a `while` loop like yours will never exit. You need to check for `EOF` in a loop that ignores input:

```
int ch;
while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
```

Answer (score 0):

- If you know you're reading from `stdin`, use `getchar`.
- If you're reading from an arbitrary file pointer, use `getc`.
- If for some obscure reason you need to ensure that you're calling an actual function rather than a macro, use `fgetc`.  (For me, those reasons are so obscure that I never call fgetc, and I recommend using `getc`.)